# Can I automatically sell junk?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Certain items are classified as junk, they do not seem to serve any useful purpose. Unfortunately they are not grouped in a separate category, they only appear in the complete list of all items in your inventory and waste space there.

Is there any way to sell all junk automatically, or at least get a list of junk items to be able to quickly sell them?

[image]

Comment: Despite being labeled as "junk", some "junk" items are usable, like the Iron Frame needed for the Kayren trap.

Comment: Except that the iron frame is labeled as a quest item and not junk, maybe they patched, I dunno. I haven't found the use for junk yet but I am assuming if its labelled that way it can go, hope I don't kick myself for that later.

Comment: @Kingdom - the iron frame itself is a quest item, but in the Kayran trap crafting screen it's listed as junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The inventory system is quite frustrating and you have to sell everything manually. It does not even properly categorize stuff!

Comment: No, and no. No, it's not frustrating, unless you pile up on every piece of junk to sell it later. Because it won't bring much money. And no, it does categorize stuff properly. As a matter of fact this is one of few games that does this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for us PC rpg gamers, there are a few great mods who address these issues.

On [Witcher Nexus](http://witchernexus.com/downloads/categories.php) in the user interface mods section, there's a mod for better hud icons and another for better inventory.
It adds a new category for misc (junk) items, ability to sort by name or cost/weight and so on.

Also included are some nice changes to alchemy so the game won't waste your quest items on your next potion.